# Reading pdf Page Count with C++

Tags: c++, pdf

I Was trying to read the no. of pages in the given pdf using pdf (By looking for "/Count xx") but i seem to be doing something wrong. I read all the characters into the buffer and use the string class's find to get a hit. But of the many files i tried it only worked once.
What am i doing wrong ?

http://pastebin.com/2FAXPZhE

Do i have to read it line by line using getline() or something ?

PS: I do not want to use an external library as this is for my college project and i cant use external tools.

Thanks in advance.
~Deltatiger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that your method is completely unsuitable for what you are trying to accomplish. For many different reasons - and I list only a few here:

1) PDFs support incremental updates, there might be different numbers of pages in the original PDF file and in the update block at the end of the file.

2) "/Count" might be used for completely other things than the number of pages in the file.

3) Pages in a PDF file are stored in a tree structure, the "/Count" field in that tree lists the number of pages in that section of the tree. In PDF files with a number of pages you're likely to have many different objects that list a "/Count" value that has to do with pages.

The short answer is that it is impossible to properly assess the number of pages in a PDF file without understanding the PDF file format (you can download the PDF specification from the Adobe web site). You will either have to use a library that understands the file format and parses it for you or you will need to write code that does that. Which is not a small project (to say the least).

Comment: +1; to add another reason: 4) The value of the **/Count** key may be an indirect reference pointing to some completely different region of the file; but there still are many more reasons.

Comment: Nice one! Didn't think of that even :)

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that this question was asked and answered over a year ago but in case others are still looking for a solution, I offer my own C++ code now uploaded to SourceForge **[here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pdfpagecounter/code/HEAD/tree/Trunk/)**.

You will see from my code that the page count can be located in any number of tricky places, often in compressed data streams.

(I've only just translated this from some Delphi code I wrote quite a few years ago so it's probably wise to treat this as a beta release in case there are any translation bugs. Nevertheless, it has passed a moderate amount of testing.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread but I would suggest using `PoDoFo` library for extracting the PDF page count (or any other information).

Below is a code snippet for extracting the PDF page count.

Example:

```
namespace pdf = PoDoFo;
pdf::PdfMemDocument document;
document.Load( "mypdf.pdf" );
int pgcount{ document.GetPageCount( ) };
```